# Padding not working in anchor

Tags: html, css, anchor, padding

My text inside anchor is not taking padding, but padding applies when it's hovered. That's why on hover my web structure is just moving. Please help.

Comment: Give us your HTML and CSS, and we'll check it out.

Comment: Anchor tag is an Inline element. Padding wont work with Inline Element. You have to make it as block element

Comment: @Deekey: yes it does: http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/4d7q6gwp/

Answer (score 36):

Anchor links (`a` elements) are inline elements, they can't have paddings. Making them inline-block must work.

Just add:

```
a
{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: They can have paddings on left and right..top and bottom also it has.. but doesn't take up the space

Comment: Oh yes. I want to say that.

Answer (score 8):

Anchor is an inline element so padding will work but it will not take up the space on top and bottom. Elements get overlapped. So make it `inline-block` or `block` based on your requirement.

```
<a href="#" style="display:block;padding:10px">Click here</a>
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to apply either `display:block` or `display:inline-block` to the anchor link

Answer (score 6):

Just add this CSS `display:block` on your anchor tag

```
<a href="#" style="display:block; padding:4px ">Click here</a>
```

Comment: Why? It also works without that: http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/4d7q6gwp/

Comment: it works but doesn't take up the space. add one more line and see it will overlap as it is an inline element.

Comment: @LinkinTED Padding can be applied to an inline element, but only the left and right padding will have effect on the surrounding content. Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/vinith98/u79egvjm/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4d7q6gwp/2/

Comment: @VinithAlmeida: yes, that is right.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `padding`, I am assuming you also have a defined `background-color` and maybe `border`. If you are using a `border`, make sure the same `border-width` is set for the link in all states; in the states you don’t want it to show, set it the same colour as your background. When you’ve done this, it will not move the text around it when you hover/click on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-info" role="button">button</a>
```

Comment: A user flagged this answer for deletion as low-quality and I am reviewing it. I am not voting to delete it, but while this code may answer the question it would be better to include some context explaining how and why it works. Code-only answers do not teach anyone anything.